# If $f$ is integrable and and $g=f$ except at fintely many points. Prove that $g$ is integrable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

> Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be integrable and let $g=f$ except at fintely many points. Show that $g$ is integrable and that $\int_A f = \int_A g$

The question above is from Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" question 3-2 in the chapter on integration.

I want to prove this by using the theorem that states that a function is integrable iff $ \exists p $ such that $U(f,p)-L(f,p) < \epsilon$ $, \forall \epsilon$

Since I can assume that this condition holds for $f$ I want to find a partition $p'$ such that $U(g,p') \leq U(f,p)$ and $L(g,p') > L(f,p)$.

I have tried by starting with the case where $f$ and $g$ only differ at one point.  It is then clear that in the case where $g(x_0) > f(x_0)$, that we can satisfy the inequality $U(g,p') \leq U(f,p)$ by refining the $p$ that satisfies $U(f,p)-L(f,p) < \epsilon$.

**My Question**
How can I precisely pick $p'$ so that $U(g,p')=U(f,p)$ in the special case I described above?  Intuitively, I can just keep refining $p$ and that partition which includes $x_0$ will tend to $0$, but I want to rigorously know at what point will $U(g,p')=U(f,p)$?

Thanks

Comment: The refinement may strictly decrease the upper sum, you can't ensure exact equality between them. In any case, think of the worst case scenario, where $f(x_0)$ was the maximum on its interval in $p$ and now $g(x_0)$ is a bit bigger, say by $a$. How exactly can you refine near $x_0$ so that $U(g,p')$ is close enough to $U(f,p')$? You'll need the interval containing $x_0$ to be short...how short?

Comment: In the second last line of your comment, did you mean to write "close enough to $U(f,p)$ instead of "close enough to $U(f,p')$?

Comment: No, it is easier to compare on the same partition. Then $U(f,p')$ will be close enough to $U(f,p)$ because $U(f,p)$ is already quite close to the integral of $f$.

Comment: Please, please be careful with your order of quantifiers.